# JSON - from regex to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

how do you get objects for events -> performances -> name & occurs_at to this json file https://api.myjson.com/bins/w05x using javascript. Cannot use regex since json API keeps changing format. Thanks

Comment: See [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object) and [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Can you please show what you've tried? For just accessing data given as JSON, you shouldn't have any need for using Regex. While the data in the document may change, the structure / arrangement of the data should remain fairly similar (the root value is an object, its `events` is an array of more objects, etc.), barring the developers behind the API being terribly inconsistent. If you're not sure how to start, the 2nd Q&A I linked to offers a good explanation on how to traverse the objects and arrays holding the data you'd like to access.

Comment: I tried this regex (?<=occurs_at\"\:\").*?(?=\")|(?<=\"performer\"\:\{\"slug\"\:\").*?(?=\"\,\")|(?<=location\"\:\").*?(?=\,\") and amaybe a week or two it changes so I have to update regex everytime it happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [JSON parser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
obj = JSON.parse(json_string);
```

then you access it with

```
obj.events[event_index].performances[performance_index].performer.name

obj.events[event_index].name

obj.events[event_index].occurs_at
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kLjf1kye/) of listing all the event attributes `name` and `occurs_at`.

Comment: Sorry to bother. Can you show it on jsfiddle or codepen. Thanks. appreciate your answer

Comment: @markosmarkos I added an JSFiddle example.

Comment: OMG! thanks so much gre_gor.